# Float left - float right breaks in IE9 only?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float, line-breaks

Hm, I cannot work this out, seems like all "capable" browsers can handle this (including IE8 and that's not even capable, hah) but IE9 can't. I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="contact_info_city" id="contact_info_cityX">
    <h3>City name</h3>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p class="office_tel"><span class="tel_text">Tel.:</span><span class="tel_no">+000 000 000 000</span></p>
            <p class="office_email"><span class="email_text">Email:</span><span class="email_address">somelonglongemailaddressthatdoesntfit@site.com</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#contact_info_cityX {
    width: 500px;
}
.contact_info_city h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    height: 56px;
}
.contact_info_city > div > div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact_info_city > div {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
.office_tel {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.office_tel .tel_text {
    color: #262626;
    float: left;
}
.office_tel .tel_no {
    float: right;
}
.office_email {
    font-size: 16px;
    clear: both;
}
.office_email .email_text {
    color: red;
    float: left;
}
.office_email .email_address {
    color: red;
    float: right;
}
```

Basically all it does is:
It puts a h3 city name, and aligns (or should) the tel. and email texts to the left, each on its own line, while putting the actual phone number and email address to the right of the respective text. If the email address is longer than the phone number, it should simply align them to the right with a bigger spacing between "Tel.: " and the *phone number*.
This is what I would expect to see (all browsers except of IE9):

[image: All browsers]

This is what I see in IE9 (smaller picture as just took a screen from browserstack):

[image]

I don't understand the linebreak before the email address. Anybody knows how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcKdC/2/)

Comment: Question: Why you need to have two different spans in a paragraph if you are sure that is the value you needed to keep? won't just this helps? -> <span class="email_text">Email:somelonglongemailaddressthatdoesntfit@site.com</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so you should REALLY clean this up (you are not using classes very effectively, i just did not have the time to clean it up), but I updated your HTML to have some additional classes:

```
<div class="contact_info_city" id="contact_info_cityX">
    <h3>City name</h3>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p class="office_tel item"><span class="tel_text label">Tel.:</span><span class="tel_no value">+000 000 000 000</span></p>
            <p class="office_email item"><span class="email_text label">Email:</span><span class="email_address value">somelonglongemailaddressthatdoesntfit@site.com</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And got rid of all the floats and crap, using `display:inline-block;` and `text-align` instead:

```
#contact_info_cityX {
    width: 500px;
}
.contact_info_city h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    height: 56px;
}
.contact_info_city > div > div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact_info_city > div {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
.office_tel {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.office_tel .tel_text {
    color: #262626;
    text-align: left;
}
.office_tel .tel_no {
    text-align: right;
}
.office_email {
    font-size: 16px;
    clear: both;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.office_email .email_text {
    text-align:left;
}
.office_email .email_address {
    color: red;
    text-align:right;
}

.item span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;

    /* make inline-block work on IE6 and 7 */
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
}

.label {
    width:10%;
}

.value {
    width:90%;
}
```

This creates the effect you are looking for. [Here is a jsFiddle to prove it.](http://jsfiddle.net/kqPZE/2/)

Just as a side note, get more comfortable with the `display` property and its variety of uses. `float`s are just ... awful, archaic CSS pieces that have much cleaner and easier-to-manage replacement methods (`display:inline-block` being a great starting point). Just some friendly advice.

Comment: Nop, makes no difference at all.

Comment: Interesting, this looks more like it! Gotta run now but I will check it within 2-3 hours & leave feedback.

Comment: Very nice, does setting lower % in widths affect something? I guess I will go with this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough space for that long email address to fit? It looks like its running out of room so it is dropping to the next line.

Comment: The main div has 500px width which should be more than sufficient. It drops to the next line as soon as it is longer than the phone number.

Comment: That one works - the problem is it keeps too big space between the "email: " and the *email address*. I don't know the email address in advance which may yield in really big spacing.

Comment: instead of floating right, you could put a specific width for the left items or a right padding. Or reduce the container width.